# Write logs to a buffer then dump the buffer in to another logger later using serilog?

Tags: logging, serilog

How can I write Logs to a buffer then dump the buffer into another logger later?

So I have kind of a catch 22. I want to log everything from the start of the application, but then I want to be able to set the logging file location in a config file. So I figured I could create a logger just for a startup with a fixed path. If any issues go wrong loading the config they will be logger. Then from there create a new logger for the rest of the application to use, but I want to be able to have the startup logger dump all of it's logs in to the main logger after it is created how can I do that.

```
//** Configure Start Up Logger. The purpose of this logger is to contain errors about configuration, template files and anything 
//** else that can be determined at startup to cause issues for program execution.
var StartupLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(startupLoggerPath)
    .CreateLogger();


StartupLogger.Information("Log Some Stuff");



//** Configure Master Logger. All other loggers log to this logger. This provides a catch all for all log statements
var MasterLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File(RootLoggingDirectoryPath, flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 730)
    .CreateLogger();

//** How do I dump the StartUp Log into the Master Logger? Can I go to some kind of buffer then dump it to the Master?
```